# java.lang.NullPointerException at net.sf.sahi.config.Configuration.getUserProperty

Tags: java, maven, sahi

Here is my **code**. Cant figure out why i am getting the exception.

```
import net.sf.sahi.client.Browser;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;


public class browser {


@Test
public void function2(){
    System.out.println("Starting");
    String browserName = "firefox"; // default values are "ie", "firefox", "safari", "chrome", "opera" - specified in userdata/config/browser_types.xml
    Browser browser = new Browser(browserName);
    browser.open();
    browser.navigateTo("http://www.google.com");
    browser.textbox("q").setValue("sahi forums");
    browser.submit("Google Search").click();
    browser.link("Sahi - Web Automation and Test Tool").click();
    browser.link("Login").click();
    Assert.assertTrue(browser.textbox("req_username").exists());

    browser.close();

    System.out.println("Ending");
}
}


 import org.testng.annotations.Test;

 public class trial {

 @Test
 public void function2(){
    browser.function1();
   }
 }
```

My **pom.xml** looks like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
     http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>rashmi</groupId>
<artifactId>sahi</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>


    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>clojars</id>
            <name>Clojars Repository</name>
            <url>http://clojars.org/repo</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>sahi</groupId>
            <artifactId>sahi</artifactId>
            <version>3.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.8.8</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

</project>
```

When I right click on my test and run it the **exception** I am getting is as follows:

```
  java.lang.NullPointerException
          at net.sf.sahi.config.Configuration.getUserProperty(Configuration.java:694)
at net.sf.sahi.config.Configuration.getCommonDomain(Configuration.java:780)
at net.sf.sahi.client.Browser.openURL(Browser.java:265)
at net.sf.sahi.client.Browser.open(Browser.java:241)
at browser.function1(browser.java:15)
at trial.function2(trial.java:12)
```

Can somebody please help me figure out why I am getting the exception?

Comment: can you paste function1() in browser file and trial file too.

Comment: There is no function1. I just randomly named as finction2()

Comment: Your error says `at browser.function1(browser.java:15)
at trial.function2(trial.java:12)`

which means it should be there.

Comment: function1 just calls function2()

Comment: what is line 15 in browser.java file?

Comment: line 15 is browser.open();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the javadoc of [Browser](https://sahipro.com/java/javadocs/net/sf/sahi/client/Browser.html) shows, the following should be done first, before `open`.

```
String sahiBasePath = "D:\\path\\to\\sahi_dir";
Sting userDataDirectory = "D:\\path\\to\\userdata_dir";

net.sf.sahi.config.Configuration.initJava(sahiBasePath, userDataDirectory);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I added the following lines to my code.                                  String sahiBasePath="/workspace/Sahi_1/sahi";
        String userDataDirectory = "/worspace/Sahi_1/sahi/userdata";
        net.sf.sahi.config.Configuration.initJava(sahiBasePath, userDataDirectory);

Comment: Starting
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /workspace/Sahi_1/config/sahi.properties (No such file or directory)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
 at net.sf.sahi.config.Configuration.loadProperties(Configuration.java:121)
 at net.sf.sahi.config.Configuration.init(Configuration.java:95)
 at net.sf.sahi.config.Configuration.initJava(Configuration.java:145)
 at browser.function1(browser.java:17)
 at trial.function2(trial.java:12)

Comment: Sahi properties file = /workspace/Sahi_1/config/sahi.properties
 at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)

Comment: Sahi user properties file = /worspace/Sahi_1/sahi/config/userdata.properties
 at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
 at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
 at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
 at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
 at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
 at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:348)

Comment: at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:343)
 at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:305)
 at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:254)
 at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
 at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
 at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
 at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
 at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
 at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)

Comment: at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
 at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
 at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:125)

Comment: `System.getProperty("user.home") + "/workspace/Sahi_1/config/sahi.properties"` - a path relative to the home directory would seem better.